# Values of generated column not appearing in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I'm using mysql version `5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)`.

```
mysql> show create table tt\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tt
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tt` (
  `pz` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` decimal(23,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `pz` (`pz`),
  KEY `uz` (`uz`),
  KEY `os` (`os`),
  KEY `pz_2` (`pz`,`uz`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select pz,uz,pz*uz,
    -> if(pz*uz,1,.5),
    -> left(pz,2) pl,left(lpad(uz,5,0),2) ul,
    -> p from tt limit 10;
+-------+----+-------+----------------+--------+----+--------+
|   pz  | uz | pz*uz | if(pz*uz,1,.5) |   pl   | ul |    p   |
+-------+----+-------+----------------+--------+----+--------+
|  NULL |  0 |  NULL |            0.5 | NULL   | 00 |   4080 |
|  NULL |  0 |  NULL |            0.5 | NULL   | 00 | 323754 |
| 89101 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 89     | 00 |   6880 |
|     0 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 0      | 00 |  11591 |
| 89110 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 89     | 00 |     72 |
| 78247 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 78     | 00 |     27 |
| 90062 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 90     | 00 |      5 |
| 63107 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 63     | 00 |      4 |
|  NULL |  0 |  NULL |            0.5 | NULL   | 00 |  54561 |
| 94102 |  0 |     0 |            0.5 | 94     | 00 |  12499 |
+-------+----+-------+----------------+--------+----+--------+
```

So far so good. As you see, 0.5 appears as a value of `if(pz*uz,1,.5)`. The problem is:

```
mysql> select os,
    -> if(pz*uz,left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2),.5) uptwo,
    -> if(pz*uz,left(pz,3)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),3),.5) upthree,
    -> sum(p) p,sum(c) c
    -> from tt t
    -> group by os,uptwo,upthree order by null;

+----+-------+---------+---------+-------+
| os | uptwo | upthree |    p    |   c   |
+----+-------+---------+---------+-------+
| u  |     1 |       1 |   52852 |   318 |
| i  |     1 |       1 | 7046563 | 21716 |
| m  |     1 |       1 | 1252166 |  7337 |
| i  |     0 |       0 | 1830284 |  4033 |
| m  |     0 |       0 |  294612 |  1714 |
| i  |     1 |       0 |  911486 |  3560 |
| m  |     1 |       0 |  145182 |  1136 |
| u  |     0 |       0 |   12144 |    23 |
| u  |     1 |       0 |    1571 |     8 |
+----+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Although I `group by uptwo`, 0.5 doesn't appear in that column. What happened to the 0.5 values?

---

*Edit:* As noted in the comments to [Todd Gibson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10885722), I also tried it with
`if(pz*uz,cast(left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2) as decimal),.5)` instead of
`if(pz*uz,left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2),.5)`, but it, too, didn't work.

Comment: No idea how to tag this. Anyone who can do so, please do!

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean with 'What happened to the 0.5 values in the column uptwo (and upthree, actually)?' what do you want to know?

Comment: @jcho360, as you see from the stuff above the "So far so good", 0.5 appears as a value of `uptwo`; yet when I `group by uptwo` in the last query, 0.5 doesn't appear. I'll edit the content of this comment into the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.5` as the false condition of the `IF()`, use `0.5`.

```
if(pz*uz,left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2),0.5) uptwo

if(pz*uz,left(pz,3)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),3),0.5) upthree
```

I believe what is happening is that after the `GROUP BY` is evaluated, the values in the conditional column must be of the same data type. Since `SELECT` is evaluated after `GROUP BY`, the `IF()` is converting the returned values in favor of an integer (from the boolean expression), and thus your `0.5` gets rounded up to `1` but if you explicitly put a `0` in front of the decimal place, the `IF()` will treat returned values as a decimal including the result of the boolean expression (i.e. `1.0` or `0.0`).

Or you could even put single quotes around the `.4` so that the column values will be treated as strings, so some values would *appear* to be integers and some decimals. The values should be automatically converted when used in numerical contexts (i.e. `SELECT ('2.5' * 3.5) AS test #8.75`).

Comment: Many thanks!! I don't get *why* `if` differentiates between `.5` and `0.5` (sounds like a bug to me), but your suggestion of using `0.5` instead of `.5` worked. (Alas, I cannot upvote your answer, because I no longer (after offering this bounty) have rep to upvote. I do plan to award it the checkmark and the bounty, though, but will give others a chance to comment on it first to be sure nothing's wrong with the answer that I don't see.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the uptwo and upthree columns are being implicitly converted to integers.  Use a convert() on expression2 to force it to a decimal.

Comment: Possible, I suppose, but unlikely, inasmuch as that same problem doesn't show up in the column `if(pz*uz,1,.5)` in the first `select` query I list. But okay, I'll try it.... [Some time later:] I tried the same query as the last one I list in the question but with `cast(... as decimal)` around the definitions of the columns `uptwo` and `upthree`, and again with `cast` around the second argument of `if` and I still got only 0 and 1 as values. So I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: @msh210 Read [Function if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: Do the cast only around the expressions 'left(pz,3)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),3)'

Comment: @ToddGibson, yeah, I tried that also (probably edited my comment above while you were posting yours). No dice.

Comment: @Ravinder, that says that if the 3rd argument of `if` is .5 then the result should not be an integer no matter what the second argument is.

Comment: @msh210 Ya. I too read that. But your question is not that. It is why value of `expr3` i.e. `.5` is not returned. But question is not an `int` or `float` return type!

Comment: @Ravinder, thanks, but I don't think that's the issue. Consider again the column `if(pz*uz,1,.5)` in the first `select` query I list.

Comment: @msh210 btw what is the MySQL version you have. Mine is `5.0.22-community-nt`. On which `if` is functioning as defined.

Comment: @msh210 I tested similar expressions on my version and the results were as defined in Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in the following statements:

```
-> if(pz*uz,left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2),.5) uptwo,
-> if(pz*uz,left(pz,3)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),3),.5) upthree,
```

In the statement the value of `pz*uz` must always be `greater than or equal to 1`.
And hence value of first expression is used to replace over second expression `0.5`.

Let us analyse first `if` function statement:
**Syntax**: `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)`
Meaning `if value of expr1 is >= 1 use expr1 else use expr3`
**Expression1**: `pz*uz` // this value must be `'>= 1'`.
**Expression2**: `left(pz,2)<=>left(lpad(uz,5,0),2)` // this value is either `'1'` or `'0'`.
**Expression3**: `.5`

Comment: Why do you think `pz*uz` is always >=1? See the columns `pz*uz` and `if(pz*uz,1,.5)` in the first `select` query I list.

Comment: I am not thinking but your results are forcing to think like that. See the meaning of syntax I posted.

Comment: @msh210 Read [Function if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: I've done so (anyway, and again because you advised me to do so in a comment on the other answer); for what purpose are you pointing it out in a comment on this answer? Is there something specific on that Web page that I should read, which is relevant to my comment on this answer?

Comment: @msh210 hey Cool man. I just pointed to a detailed notes page. It is just for your reference.